# How To set Value and show it in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I'm trying to set a Value and show it in a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.

I have created my DataGridView and i added a column as a type of DataGridViewComboBoxColumn .

when i run my program, everything works , but i want to set and show the default item of my DataGridViewComboBoxColumn automatically, same as in

```
        java ( combobox.addItem("it"); //
```

the item 'it' is shown automatically, we don't need to open the combobox and select it manually.. )

My DataGridView is called : 'Table_Items'
I wrote the code as below:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{

base.OnLoad(e);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("Status");
dt.Columns.Add("Value");

dt.Rows.Add("Status 1", "Available");
dt.Rows.Add("Status 2", "Reserved");
dt.Rows.Add("Status 3", "Ordered");

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

cmb.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 8, FontStyle.Bold);
cmb.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.BlueViolet;
cmb.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
cmb.Name = "CmboColumnSample";
cmb.HeaderText = "CmboColumnSample";

cmb.DisplayMember = "Status";
cmb.ValueMember = "Value";

Table_Items.Columns.Add(cmb);
cmb.DataSource = dt;

for (int i = 0; i < Table_Items.RowCount; i++)
{
Table_Items.Rows[i].Cells["CmboColumnSample"].Value = (cmb.Items[1] as DataRowView).Row[1].ToString();

}
}
```

I think I did not explain my problem very well, so i made this picture to explain it better:

[image]

I googled a lot , i found a similar question in this link :

[how to set SelectedIndex in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825222/how-to-set-selectedindex-in-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn)

but all the answers do not conform with the question !! :(

Sorry if my english isn't good and thank you in advance :)
BinaryMan

Comment: Try calling databind() on each of the combo boxes

Comment: @BinaryMan - i just copy pasted your code in my sample program and it works as you expected. Strange! do you get any error message or exception?

Comment: Works for me either. And you need to change it to `cmb.Items[0]` to get the "Status 1" item, as in your image.
Do you have other events that may interfere?

Comment: Thank you all, thanks for helps, i think that i have a stupid fault :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the null value before adding to the DataGridView.

```
cmb.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "Status 1";
```

The first solution worked for me because I used items instead of a DataSource. But instead you can try the value member.

```
cmb.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "Available";
```

Let me know what worked for you.

Comment: Dear, thank you for your response, but this is a very old question (see date, 2014) and so I can not check the correctness of your answer ...
Regards.