# Updating ComboBox Column in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I am populating my datagridview with the below code.

```
dgvPChannel.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dgvPChannel.DataSource = new PaymentsAccess().getAllComplianceAccounts().ToList();
```

I have created an extra column in the datagridview and populated this combobox column. I will now need to update my database when changing this combobox to an option on and 'Update' button. How can I update all my datagridview items with the combo box option chosen for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you loop through each ComboBox value in your grid, you can update rows that checked. check this:

```
   private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in yourdataGridView.Rows)
        {
            var comboValue = string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[ComboBoxColumnName.Index].Value.ToString()) ? "" : row.Cells[ComboBoxColumnName.Index].Value.ToString();
            if (some logic here to update)
            {
                //update your_table set field = value where id = row.Cells["fieldname"].Value;
               

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: its a combobox not checkbox

Comment: ok thank you very much I will work on that and let you know, by any chance how do I set my combobox selected item. For example if row.cells[1].value == "A" combox selectedindex 1. Any help please?

Comment: nevermind got my answer from here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825222/how-to-set-selectedindex-in-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn